# Algorithm to figure out what an include command resolves to

Tags: python, algorithm, comparison

Let's say we have a directory full of files (let's call it file structure A, FSA) with blocks of code like this:

```
<div class="Look out its a div" id="look-out">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#{Include_Path}/" lang="en">#{Variable_Home}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#{Include_Book}/account.php">#{Variable_Account}</a></li>
        <li lang="en">#{Variable_BookName}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All of those `#{}` helpers are including some other template data and plugging it into this template, and this template itself might be included somewhere else. That compilation process occurs on a closed server, so we don't have access to exactly how it all works.

However, the compiled files are then used to serve a normal website, which can be crawled completely using `wget`.

So, using `wget` we have a file structure (file structure B, FSB) that is completely dissimilar from FSA but must necessarily be derived from it.

Let's say that the above code block theoretically compiled to something like this:

```
<div class="Look out its a div" id="look-out">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/include/path/" lang="en">Welcome Home!</a></li>
        <li><a href="/various/account.php">Hello Mr. Jenkins</a></li>
        <li lang="en">Book Book Book</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but that compiled version is also "hidden" among a huge mish-mash of other similar things, in the completely dissimilar FSB.

**How would we glean what the various `#{}` helpers actually compile to, so that we could compile the original files but keep them neatly decomposed in FSA?**

What algorithm would even be used to do such a thing?

Comment: You want to reverse ingeneering a template system in order to determine the values that get populated in these templates you have access too... This seems useless and tedious task... If you have access to the templates it most probably because you have access to the server and script that generate the final HTML files... So I would suggest to invest some times to find out which script is used to populate these templates and read it and understand it... For this purpose `grep` may be useful.

Comment: I explained in the post that, although I have the templates, I don't have access to the compilation process in any way. Essentially these templates are given to a third party service and compiled "behind closed doors". If I could have just gotten access to that compilation process, I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: You can use webcrawler to navigate the site and you may be able to extract all data from the database that way if you visit all the available page if there is a way for you to surf all this page (let say increment record ID in the URL for instance)... Then the only task of the template system is to display data pass to it from the controller basically... So what you would do is to reverse engineering the controller code which maybe very difficult without knowing what the database schema look like... So, does it worth the efforts to do such a thing?